# DeployableContainer must be specified error when running Arquillian

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I've been trying to run this Arquillian example

https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/tree/master/arquillian-tutorial

There is no error when imported in Eclipse

However I am getting this error when I run as **JUnit Test**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container jbossas-managed
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeployableContainer must be specified
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: How is your JBoss setup on the workstation you are trying this on? Have you configured the JBOSS_HOME environment variable?

Comment: yes the %JBOSS_HOME% is configured in my pc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The project POM defines a bunch of profiles - `arquillian-weld-ee-embedded`, `arquillian-glassfish-embedded`, and `arquillian-jbossas-managed`. None of them are active by default. You need to activate one of these to run the tests, since the profiles bring in the Arquillian container adapter.

Without a container adapter in the classpath, you're likely to see an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` exception with the message "DeployableContainer must be specified".

Comment: Do you have any idea about fixing that problem with gradle?, I mean how should I define the DeployableContainer?

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Let me be more particular and add that the problem is here (for me it was as follows)
<code><profiles>
        <profile>

            <id>my-favorite-profile</id>

            <dependencies>

                <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>

                    <artifactId>arquillian-wlp-managed-8.5</artifactId>

                    <version>${arquillian.version}</version>

                </dependency>

            </dependencies>

        </profile>

    </profiles>
</code>

Answer (score 3):

Seems like QuickStrat description is quite ambiguous. To enable `arq-jboss-remote` profile by default you could simply add:

```
 <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
 </activation>
```

into this profile definition in a project `pom.xml`.